# Algorithm from C++ to Python (radial symmetry transform)

Tags: python, c++, algorithm

I have to transform the radial symmetry transform algorithm from C++ to Python. I'm very new to python and have never used C++.

```
void RadSymTransform(InputArray gradx,InputArray grady,OutputArray result,int ray,double minval=0,double maxval=255)
{
Mat gxMat=gradx.getMat();
Mat gyMat=grady.getMat();
result.create(gradx.size(), CV_16UC1);
Mat resMat=result.getMat();
resMat=Mat::zeros(resMat.size(), resMat.type());
int x,y,i,H,W;
double tx,ty,gx,gy,ampl,max;
H=gxMat.rows;W=gxMat.cols;
for(y=0;y<H;y++)
    for (x = 0; x < W; x++)
    {
        gx=gxMat.at<double>(y,x);
        gy=gyMat.at<double>(y,x);
        ampl=sqrt(gx*gx+gy*gy);
        if((ampl>minval)&&(ampl<maxval)){
            max=(abs(gx)>abs(gy)?abs(gx):abs(gy));
            gx/=max;gy/=max;
            tx=x-ray*gx;ty=y-ray*gy;
            if(tx<0||tx>W||ty<0||ty>H)continue;
            tx=x;ty=y;
            for (i = 0; i < ray; ++i)
            {
                tx-=gx;ty-=gy;
                resMat.at<ushort>((int)ty,(int)tx)++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It takes the x and y gradients and the detection radius (ray). minval and maxval are low and high thresholds for the gradient.

The algorithm should transform the coin image down below to the radial symmetry transform.

[image]
[image]

This is my python version, but unfortunately I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Christian/PycharmProjects/symmetry_transform4/RadSymTransform.py", line 74, in <module>
    print(radSymTransform(gray, 60, 0, 255))
  File "C:/Users/Christian/PycharmProjects/symmetry_transform4/RadSymTransform.py", line 64, in radSymTransform
    result[ty, tx] = result[ty, tx] + 1
IndexError: index 1024 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1024
```

code:

```
import cv2
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math


# x gradient
def gradx(img):
    img = img.astype('int')
    rows, cols = img.shape
    # Use hstack to add back in the columns that were dropped as zeros
    return np.hstack((np.zeros((rows, 1)), (img[:, 2:] - img[:, :-2]) / 2.0, np.zeros((rows, 1))))


# y gradient
def grady(img):
    img = img.astype('int')
    rows, cols = img.shape
    # Use vstack to add back the rows that were dropped as zeros
    return np.vstack((np.zeros((1, cols)), (img[2:, :] - img[:-2, :]) / 2.0, np.zeros((1, cols))))


# img -> gray-scale image
# Detection radius ray
# minVal -> low threshold for the gradient
# maxVal -> low threshold for the gradient
def radSymTransform(img, ray, minVal, maxVal):
    #gxMat = gradx(img)
    #gyMat = grady(img)

    gxMat = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=5)
    gyMat = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=5)

    gxMatShape = gradx(img).shape

    result = np.zeros(img.shape)
    # test = vGradx.getMat()

    # image height = number of rows
    # image width = number of columns
    height = gxMatShape[0]
    width = gxMatShape[1]

    y = 0  # counter 1: y-coordinate
    x = 0  # counter 2: x-coordinate

    while y < height:
        while x < width:
            gx = gxMat[y, x]
            gy = gyMat[y, x]
            ampl = math.sqrt(gx * gx + gy * gy)

            if ampl > minVal and ampl < maxVal:
                maxXY = max(abs(gx), abs(gy))
                gx = gx / maxXY
                gy = gy / maxXY
                tx = x - ray * gx
                ty = y - ray * gy
                if tx < 0 or tx > width or ty < 0 or ty > width:
                    tx = x
                    ty = y

                i = 0  # counter 3
                while i < ray:
                    tx = int(tx - gx)
                    ty = int(ty - gy)
                    # Increment result at position (tx,ty)
                    if tx < width and ty < height:
                        result[ty, tx] = result[ty, tx] + 1
                    i = i + 1
            x = x + 1
        x = 0
        y = y + 1

    return result


img = cv2.imread('data/P1190263.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

result = radSymTransform(gray, 60, 0, 255)
print(result)
cv2.imshow("Output:", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I would be grateful for any advice what I did wrong.

**Edit:** I just added a condition that it's not allowed to run out of borders, but the output is to high, this means just a white image:

[image]

**Edit 2:** I changed the parameters to `radSymTransform(gray, 1, 250, 255)` (first) and `radSymTransform(gray, 10, 250, 255)` (second) and I got this output which is also not very good:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to tell us what line of code is causing this error, but I think it would be even more useful for you to step through your python code with a debugger and see what's going on step by step

Comment: I don't think this is the source of the error, but I happened to notice that you do `while x < width:...` but don't set `x = 0` inside the y loop

Comment: Why you use while instead of for y in range(0, height)?

Comment: I added the whole error (sorry for that) and I added x = 0 inside the y loop (as you said: it wasn't the source)

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you not to use some library implementation? (Googling "python radial symmetry transform" returns a few options).

Comment: I tried that (for example this one: https://github.com/ceilab/frst_python) but it didn't worked as the algroithm seems a little bit different (I got no real results, only a nearly black output).

Comment: The linebreaks in stack traces are significant. Now that it's readable, what do the last couple of lines tell you? What are the dimensions and valid indices for `range`?

Comment: The algorithm wanted to increase a position in the array (image) that is not there. It is a 768x1024 image so from 0 to 1023. But I don't know why it's running out of bounds.

Comment: I'd use a debugger to see `tx, ty` values. Also, shouldn't `result[ty, tx]` be `result[tx, ty]` ?

Comment: tx was 1024, ty 0. But this could be fixed with the if condition. There must be an other mistake.

Comment: As the out of bound error is fixed, do you have any ideas why the code isn't giving good result? @Useless

Answer (score 0):

use can just use Fast Radial Symmetry Transformation built in library [link to the description](https://pypi.org/project/frst/)